# Pardot - why is using own objects and sync mechanism?

Tags: custom-object, object, pardot, sync

I am learning about Pardot Cloud.
I have searched a lot but did not find answers that will satisfy my questions.

By learning on trailhead, I know that Salesforce treats Pardot as something as "external" system with specific internal Pardot objects that are mapped to standard/custom objects in Salesforce.

Questions:

1. Why Pardot uses own objects instead of using standard Salesforce objects, or why Salesforce does not create more standard objects which fill fit Pardot requirements?
2. I cannot find metadata for for example "Prospect" object. Are they avaiable? Are they considered as Salesforce metadata object?
3. Why there is sync mechanism? Why Pardot is not operating on Salesforce records on real-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Marketing Cloud Account Engagement (Pardot) is a separate system with different codebase and database infrastructure compared to Salesforce. Salesforce acquired Pardot a few years ago, and has not yet moved everything "on platform"
2. Due to the fact that Pardot isn't "on platform", you won't find metadata for the majority of what is configurable inside Pardot. New features DO use metadata however, for example Marketing App Extensions for External Activities and External Actions. It is rumored some future enhancements will also continue to leverage metadata.
3. Sync mechanism is in place to give the appearance that Pardot and Salesforce are in fact 1 (well not strictly speaking, but generally true). Administrators actually have the choice of when a Prospect will sync into Salesforce, giving them the option of keeping (potentially garbage) records in Pardot and only sending them over once they reach a certain level of qualification.

Comment: Thank you very much for reply. So is there any way to download metadata of Pardot content to store it in GIT repository?  (Is that platform written in APEX?)

Comment: There is no way to download text-based configuration files from Pardot.